# How convert PHP value from windows-1257 to UTF-8

Tags: php, windows, utf-8

How convert PHP value from windows-1257 to UTF-8? I tried many ways, but they was not successful. I have lttu�s and I wanna convert this to littūs.

```
utf8_encode(); 
iconv_set_encoding("windows-1257", "UTF-8");
mb_convert_encoding()
```

Doesn't work. :(

Can anybody help me?

Comment: What's the character you have?  From what I can see, U0168 doesn't exist in Windows-1257 http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0168/charset_support.htm

Answer (score 9):

```
$encoded= iconv ("CP1257","UTF-8", $string)
```

Comment: worked for me , for Arabic character Encoding , many thank's bro

Answer (score 4):

Use `mb_convert_encoding($data, 'UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-13');`

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that the page you are using to display the converted string has the Encoding and CodePage set correctly?

Comment: Yes. That page is encode in UTF-8 without BOM and has <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" >.