# Writing UTF8 in .dat file from PHP script

Tags: php, utf-8

I have problem writing utf8 characters in `.dat` file from [MyGallery](http://www.planetluc.com/en/scripts_mygallery.php) (free PHP script).
The utf8 characters in `.dat` file are writen like this:

> Ð�Ð²Ð° Ðµ Ñ�Ð°Ð¼Ð¾ Ð¿Ñ�Ð¾Ð±Ð°

When I try to edit `.dat` file with utf8 character text, I'm able to see the right text in MyGallery, so the problem is with writing in `.dat` file (reading from the file is ok).

Anny suggestions?

Comment: I strongly recommend ["The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)"](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Comment: I have just written answer about this exact topic here: [PHP file_put_contents and UTF-8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11115533/php-file-put-contents-and-utf-8)

Answer (score 0):

Check [utf8_decode @ PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode.php) and [utf8_encode @ PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php) and you will find a solution within minutes